# Android - listview sometimes doesn't show nested textviews until converting view

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I'm working on an application that parses data from an external file and then creates a listview with custom adapter. The adapter inflates the individual rows from a xml layout. The row is made of two parts - the buttons part which is the same for each row and the text part, which is build dynamically from the parsed data in the source arraylist.

The problem I have is that some of the rows do not render correctly the first time around. Here is a link to an image of the desired result :
http://postimg.org/image/4dvtv8qe5/

Note the numbers between the buttons - theese represent the order of elements in source arraylist. However, when first setting the adapter to the listview, I get this result :
http://postimg.org/image/hogyy7qgh/

Several of the rows render into theese fat chunks, showing none of the textviews I added to them in the adapter. The textviews are however there - I have tried assigning IDs to them and then succesfully found them by id and returned their text.

Some of the rows render correctly the first time around. The order of the defective rows is constant between renders but changes when parsing data from a different external file.

After scrolling so that the defective row is no longer visible in the listview and scrolling back, the row in question renders correctly (that is how I got the desired result screenshot).

I can't post more than 2 links due to reputation limits but after changing the code to let the app do all the work and then set the text of the textview to "text" regardless of what it parsed, I got a similair problem. The order and quantity of defective rows changed.

It also seems like the first two rows of the listview are always defective no matter what file I parse from.

I'm running this on a Lenovo X2-EU with 4.4.2 android if that's of any help.

Thank you in advance for any aid you can give me.

Here's my custom adapter :

```
public class AdapterCardList extends ArrayAdapter {

private String TAG = "AdapterCardList";
private Context theContext;
private ArrayList<Card> theCards; //the source arraylist
public Hammer theHammer; //holds some data
public int number;

public AdapterCardList(Context context, int rowLayout, ArrayList<Card> cards, Hammer hammer) {
    super(context, rowLayout, cards);
    theCards = cards;
    theContext = context;
    theHammer = hammer;
    number = 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView;

    if ((convertView==null)){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) theContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_of_card_list, parent, false);
    }
    else{
        rowView = convertView;
    }



    LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowHorizontalTextLayout);
    rowLayout.removeAllViews();



    TextView quantText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
    quantText.setText(String.valueOf(position));


    int allCollLength = rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowHorizontalLayout).getWidth()-rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowHorizontalButtonsLayout).getWidth();
    int oneCollLength = (int)(((float)allCollLength)/(theHammer.elementsToPrint.length+1));

    Boolean toBePrinted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < theCards.get(position).returnTypesLength(); i++) {

        //I parse more info than I show in listview. Here I decide if I show.
            if (theHammer.elementsToPrint[x].equals(theCards.get(position).returnType(i))) {
                toBePrinted = true;
                x = theHammer.elementsToPrint.length;
            }
            else if (theHammer.primaryIdentifier.equals(theCards.get(position).returnType(i))) {
                toBePrinted = true;
                x = theHammer.elementsToPrint.length;

            }
            else {
                toBePrinted=false;}


        }

        if (toBePrinted) {


            Log.d(TAG, "Authorised to print the value of type " + theCards.get(position).returnType(i));
            TextView newText = new TextView(theContext);



            newText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(oneCollLength, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newText.setId(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "Set the id to " + newText.getId());

            String textToSet = theCards.get(position).returnValue(i);
            newText.setText(textToSet);
            rowLayout.addView(newText);
            Log.d(TAG, "Added the value :" + theCards.get(position).returnValue(i));

        }

    }


    return rowView;

}

}
```

and here is my layout for a row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"

android:id="@+id/rowHorizontalLayout" >



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/rowHorizontalButtonsLayout">



    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/textViewQuantity"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/button3"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/rowHorizontalTextLayout"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rowHorizontalButtonsLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false">


</LinearLayout>
```